# couldn't resole issue in react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am new at react native and I am using react-navigation for my routes
recently I found a bug in my code that I can't resolve it please help me with that

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import LandingScreen from './components/auth/landing'
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="landing">
        <Stack.Screen name="landing" component={LandingScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And the error is:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 1):

You surely forgot to export your **LandingScreen**

```
export default function LandingScreen()
```